# $f,g \in F(\Omega, \mathbb{R})$ defined by$ f(x)=e^{\ln(5 x+5)}$ and $g(x)=3 x^2+4 x+4; \forall x \in \Omega$. Evaluate $(9 f+14 g)(8)$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Suppose, $f,g \in F(\Omega,\mathbb{R})$ defined by $f(x)=e^{\ln(5 x+5)}$ and $g(x)=3 x^2+4 x+4; \forall x \in \Omega$.

Evaluate $(9 f+14 g)(8)$.

Not sure if I am correct but this is what i did:

$\begin{align}
& (9f +14g)(x) = 9f(x) + 14g(x)\\
\implies & (9f+14g)(8) = 9f(8) + 14g(8) 
\end{align}$

For $9f(8)$, I substituted $x = 8$ into $f(x)$ then multiplied that answer by $9$ to get $405$.

Similarly, for $14g(8)$, substituted $x = 8$ into $g(x)$ then multiplied by $14$ to get $3192$.

Adding them together, the final answer becomes $405 + 3192 = 3597$.

Is this correct or not?

Comment: Nash J. you edit so well

Comment: If $14(3*8^2 +4*8 + 4)=3192$ (no way I'm doing that in my head) and $9e^{\ln(5x+5)} = 405$ (which I did do in my head), then yes.  this is correct.  (Funny what you think needs spelling out vs. what I would think needs spelling out... but no matter.)

Comment: @fleablood what do you mean?

Comment: Nothing really.  you went into such detail to get that the answer is $9f(8) + 14g(8)$ then "I substituted x=8 into f(x) then multiplied that answer by 9 to get 405."  seem a little quick.  It's nothing really.